# Is there a way to export a resource from a kube cluster so that it can be applied to another cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to export some kube resources (configmaps, deployments, services)  from one cluster so that it can be applied to another.

Something like this ....

kubectl --kubeconfig ${src} -n ${ns} get configmaps ${cm} -o yaml | \
   kubectl --kubeconfig ${dst} -n ${ns} apply -f -

It kind works, once.  The first time where the resource hasn't been created yet.   If I run it a second time, trying to update the destination I get error like...

**the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again.**

I suspect it has something to do with the resourceVersion or timestamp fields that appear in the output.

Is there away to output a resource so that is striped of all server side specific info?  Other that a bunch of sed delete and grep -v statements.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command with `--export` flag to strip of cluster-specific information.

```
kubectl get cm cmname -o yaml --export > cm.yaml
```

A word of caution that `--export` is deprecated and going to be removed in future. So use it at your own risk.

Comment: It’s already deprecated. It’s going to be removed in the future.

Comment: thanks.  I did see that option but as you said, its being depricated. works for most.  ingress still seems to complain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the output data to remove some of the metadata fields like UID, creation time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, with export being depricated, I came up with this....

```
sub_string_A="resourceVersion|selfLink|uid|creationTimestamp"

sub_string_B="resourceVersion|selfLink|uid|creationTimestamp|annotations|last-applied-configuration|status|loadBalancer|clusterIP"

namespace=test

src=clusterA.yml
dst=clusterB.yml

dry_run=false

kubectl --kubeconfig ${src} -n ${namespace} get ingress -o yaml \
  | grep -v -E "${sub_string_A}" \
  | kubectl --kubeconfig ${dst} -n ${namespace} --dry-run=${dry_run} apply -f -

kubectl --kubeconfig ${src} -n ${namespace} get statefulsets -o yaml \
  | grep -v -E "${sub_string_B}" \
  | kubectl --kubeconfig ${dst} -n ${namespace} --dry-run=${dry_run} apply -f -
```

Ingress seems to behave differently than other reources.  So it get a different pattern.